# If cell A2 = cell B2 then C2's dropdown list makes a selection?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dropdown list starting at C2 with 3 strings to choose from, the list itself is on sheet2, and I need something in place that will automatically select "INSTALLED" from the dropdown if cells A$ and B$ on sheet1 are exactly the same, otherwise the dropdown should default to "UNDEFINED."

Not sure if the answer is a formula, VBA, or something else?

I can't come up with a concisely enough written google search for my specific situation, so I hope someone here can provide assistance?

My dropdown list and small sample dataset example:

[image: small sample dataset on sheet1]

[image: dropdown on sheet2]

Comment: `=IF(A1 = B1, 'INSTALLED', 'UNDEFINED')`? You don't need a drop down for this at all

Comment: `=IF(A2=B2, "INSTALLED, "UNDEFINED")` and drag down as needed

Comment: Custom dropdown for manual selection - you can add a custom dropdown like described here https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/24/excel-drop-down-list/ and automatic selection via IF function - https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that one could use =IF(A2=B2, "INSTALLED", "UNDEFINED") in conjunction with a dropdown list and its data validation restrictions. Thanks @Mech

In my case I have C2 and downward all with the formula =IF(A2=B2, "INSTALLED", "UNDEFINED") in place, and I can change the selection if I need to, it just simply breaks out of the formula if I do.

Also, the strings in the formula have to match the strings in the dropdown list or you'll get a data validation error.